# OSM data open street map R maps error code

Tags: r, maps, openstreetmap, osmdata

I want to create a map of Germany, which contains all highways and streets. And I want to add some points of special locations.

But I always get an error:

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("osmdata")
library("sf")`

land \<- 'Germany'
location \<- land %\>% opq()

Error in `httr2::req_perform()`:
! HTTP 403 Forbidden.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Is it the same for `osmdata::getbb("Germany")` ? Are you blocked from Nominatim - https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html?q=Germany ?  Or was it working (i.e. returned a different error) but you were blocked from Overpass? You probably should not use `osmdata` / Overpass API for bulk downloads and I would expect it to fail when querying the whole road network of Garemany, so perhaps opt for `osmextract` instead, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+osmextract , https://ropensci.github.io/osmextract/